# $x$ and $g$ are elements of the group $G$, show that the order of $x$ is equal to the order of $g^{-1} xg$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $x$ and $g$ are elements of the group $G$, prove that $|x| = | g^{-1} xg|$. Deduce that $|ab| = |ba|$ for all $a,b \in G$.

attempt: Let $|x| = n$ be the order of $x$ and $| g^{-1} xg| = m$ be the order of  $g^{-1} xg$. Where the order of $x$ is the smallest number $n$ such that $x^n = e$.

Then we need to show $n = m$
Then  $(g^{-1} xg)^n = (g^{-1} xg)(g^{-1} xg)...(g^{-1} xg)$  , $n$ times.
THen $(g^{-1} xg)^n = (g^{-1} xg)(g^{-1} xg)...(g^{-1} xg) = g^{-1} x^ng = g^{-1}g = e$. So $|g^{-1} xg| \leq |x|$.

I don't know how to show $|g^{-1} xg| \geq |x|$. To conclude they are equal.
Can someone please help me? Any suggestion help would really be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You should also consider the case where $x$ has infinite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^m=g(g^{-1}xg)^{m-1}g^{-1}x=g(g^{-1}xg)^{-1}g^{-1}x=e$ so $n\le m$. Then in $|ab|=|g^{-1}abg|$ let $g=a$.

Comment: what happen with the $m$ on $g(g^{-1}xg)^{-1}g^{-1}x$? would it not be $g(g^{-1}x^{m-1}g)g^{-1}x$?

Comment: @Mahidevran: Since $(g^{-1}xg)^m=e$ so multiplication on both sides by $(g^{-1}xg)^{-1}$ gives $(g^{-1}xg)^{m-1}=(g^{-1}xg)^{-1}$.

Comment: @Mahidevran: I hope my explanation was clear. By the way you can prove the same result in another way if you prove that $x\to g^{-1}xg$ is an automorphism.

Comment: yes the first explanation makes sense. thank you ! the automorphism we have not cover that yet.